# KIVY not updating UI on phone sleep mode

Tags: android, python, gps, kivy

I was again trying kivy gps example from https://github.com/kivy/plyer/blob/master/examples/gps/main.py. But the problem occurs when I press the Start button and put the phone on sleep mode(screen off), after sometimes I came back to screen and the app, only I can see a frozen gui that due to unable to update the label while on standby mode. How do I can overcome this? I want to update the label even my  phone is on sleep mode.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from plyer import gps
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock

kv = '''
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    Label:
        text: app.gps_location

    Label:
        text: app.gps_status

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '48dp'
        padding: '4dp'

        ToggleButton:
            text: 'Start' if self.state == 'normal' else 'Stop'
            on_state: app.gps.start() if self.state == 'down' else app.gps.stop()
'''


def mainthread(func):
    # This method is now part of Kivy 1.8.0. When it's released, remove it.
    def delayed_func(*args, **kwargs):
        def callback_func(dt):
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(callback_func, 0)
    return delayed_func


class GpsTest(App):

    def on_pause(self):
      # Here you can save data if needed
      return True

    def on_resume(self):
      # Here you can check if any data needs replacing (usually nothing)
      pass

    gps_location = StringProperty()
    gps_status = StringProperty('Click Start to get GPS location updates')

    def build(self):
        self.gps = gps
        try:
            self.gps.configure(on_location=self.on_location,
                    on_status=self.on_status)
        except NotImplementedError:
            import traceback; traceback.print_exc()
            self.gps_status = 'GPS is not implemented for your platform'

        return Builder.load_string(kv)

    @mainthread
    def on_location(self, **kwargs):
        self.gps_location = '\n'.join([
            '{}={}'.format(k, v) for k, v in kwargs.items()])

    @mainthread
    def on_status(self, stype, status):
        self.gps_status = 'type={}\n{}'.format(stype, status)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    GpsTest().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't ever guarantee that the app will continue operating in sleep mode, so this probably isn't a good way to do things. Better would be to use an android service, which is possible with python-for-android. [Here](http://kivy.org/planet/2014/01/building-a-background-application-on-android-with-kivy/) is a blog post about it, and it's [documented here](http://python-for-android.readthedocs.org/en/latest/android/#service-android-service).

You can do your gps stuff in the service and sync with the app on on_resume and/or on_start.